# If I delete a paid app purchased through the Mac App Store, can I redownload without paying?

Tags: applications, restore, mac-appstore

If I delete an app purchased through the Mac App Store, can I download it again without paying for it again like I can with iOS? In the event of an app restore, does the app retain settings, saved progress, etc from the previous installation?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes. Just go to the "Purchases" tab and click "Install" by the app you wish to reinstall:

[image]

Well-behaved apps should retain settings, etc upon reinstall, as merely deleting the app from /Applications is not sufficient to remove that information from your system. This may not be the case if an [app cleaner](http://www.freemacsoft.net/AppCleaner/) is used.